Clipboard.SetDataObject() COM exception DV_E_FORMATETC when getting data from keyboard and setting back
I'm trying to get IDataObject from clipboard, and setting it back after I'm done using clipboard.
// keep clipboard's data to restore it later.
IDataObject tmpClipboard = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
Clipboard.Clear();

// using the clipboard to do my things
// ...

// restore the clipboard to previous state
Clipboard.Clear();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(tmpClipboard);

This code block generally works for simple clipboard data.
However, for some data types in the clipboard (ex: bitmapsource), calling Clipboard.SetDataObject() will throw a COM exception:
Invalid FORMATETC structure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040064 (DV_E_FORMATETC)

Is it even possible to handle general-purpose clipboard data types and keep it, so I could restore it to the clipbard later?

Remarks of GetDataObject() method: "A list of predefined formats is defined by the DataFormats class". I guess you can only deal with those types. How do you find out the current data is "bitmapsource"?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78935262/14171304
